# Hiding iframe horizontal scrollbar under safari

Tags: html, iframe, safari, scrollbar

On my iframe, i want to hide the horizontal scrollbar while keeping the vertical scrollbar. I have used

> style="overflow-x: hidden;"

It works with firefox but doesn't work with safari. Is there a fix to hide horizontal scrollbar under safari ?

The only way i heard about is to change the overflow of the page inside the iframe. But i can't modify the page inside my iframe because it is an external website

Answer (score 0):

Is it a website you are passing as the URL in the iframe or is it a document.

if it is a document and when it is not possible to provide or hide horizontal or vertical scroll bars you can just set the size for document in the iframe using

Document document = new Document(PageSize.(desiredSize), 50, 50, 100, 72); 
(note: here desiredSize can be A0-A10 or B0-B5 or ARCH-A etc.)

(note: this is to be done while creating the document itself).

Please check [this](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html) link for more info on Java Class- "Document".